Can a polyhedron be uniquely indexed by its number of facets, edges and vertices?
Let $F,E,V$ be the number of facets, edges and vertices of a polyhedron in 3D space. Euler's characteristic is given by:
$$
V-E+F  =2
$$
For 3D polyhedra. I was also told that two other inequalities, according to Steinitz (in a german paper I cannot read), limit the set of all possible polyhedra:
$ F\leq2V-4 $ and $ V\leq 2 F -4 $
Given this, I was wondering whether it would be possible to uniquely index every convex polyhedra in 3D by their $(V,E,F)$ triplet.

Steinitz, E., Über die \textit{Euler}schen Polyederrelationen., Arch. der Math. u. Phys. (3) 11, 86-88 (1906). ZBL37.0500.01.

Nope, tetragonal antiwedge and pentagonal pyramid are two hexahedra with same $(V,E,F) = (6,10,6)$

@achillehui Nailed it. Could you turn that into a full-fledged answer? If no one else answer that in 24 hours, I'll just take your answer to resolve the question.

@achillehui Is theer another set of values that could uniquely index polyhedra in 3D, though?

@urquiza - Even if you consider separately the numbers of trigonal faces, tetragonal faces, pentagonal faces, etc., and also the numbers of trivalent vertices, tetravalent vertices, pentavalent vertices, etc., it is not enough. The "elongated square gyrobicupola", and the related uniform polyhedron, have all these numbers in common. -- I think this is similar to the graph isomorphism problem, and you're unlikely to find a solution.

What you looking for is the so called face vector $vec(f) = (f_0, f_1, f_2, ...)$, where $f_k$ is the count of "faces" (elements) of dimension $k$ of a given polyhedron (or, more generally: polytope) $P$.
Polytopes, which happen to have the same face vector, are called twins.
Obviously, when considering non-convex polyhedra as well, then eg. the icosahedron and the great icosahedron would be twins, and some other pairs of regular polyhedra would exist.
When restricting to convex polyhedra, @achillehui already provided an example pair of twins. However, the tetragonal antiwedge surely is neither a uniform polyhedron, nor can it be realised with all unit edges only.
But even when considering convex polyhedra with all unit edges only, there are lots of examples: severals of the Johnson solids show up subsymmetrical diminishings or extensions, which then allow for according application at/in different locations/orientations (eg. parabidiminishing -vs.- metabidiminishing, orthobicupola -vs.- gyrobicupola, etc.).
Beside such more trivial examples there are still other true twins in that given set of convex polyhedra with all unit edges only. Some examples would be:

$vec(f) = (12,24,14)$: cuboctahedron -vs.- hexagonal antiprism
$vec(f) = (14,26,14)$: bilunabirotunda -vs.- parabiaugmented hexagonal prism (or: metabiaugmented ...)
$vec(f) = (20,30,12)$: dodecahedron -vs.- decagonal prism
$vec(f) = (24,36,14)$: truncated cube -vs.- truncated octahedron
$vec(f) = (30,60,32)$: icosidodecahedron -vs.- elongated pentagonal orthobicupola (or: ... gyrobicupola)
$vec(f) = (60,90,32)$: truncated icosahedron -vs.- truncated dodecahedron

--- rk

I immediately remembered $(12,18,8)$: truncated tetrahedron vs. hexagonal prism.
